# Best way to write generic factory in Java

Tags: java, generics, factory-method

I need to write a factory of generic converters to produce converters from/to MongoDB objects to/from Java objects. Here is my implementation, it doesn't look good enough to me, so I would like to see your advice.

```
public static <T> Converter<T> getConverter(final Class<T> clazz) {
    return new Converter<T>() {
        public DBObject convert(T t) {
            if (clazz == Manager.class) {
                BasicDBObject dbObject = new BasicDBObject();
                dbObject.append("age", ((Manager) t).getAge());
                dbObject.append("id", ((Manager) t).getId());
                return dbObject;
            }
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Unsuported Object Type " + clazz);
        }

        public T convert(DBObject o) {
            if (clazz == Manager.class) {
                int age= Integer.valueOf((String) o.get("age"));
                int id= Integer.valueOf((String) o.get("id"));
                Manager t = new Manager(id, age);
                return (T) t;
            }
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Unsuported Object Type " + clazz);
        }
    };
}
```

Comment: Can you post a code snippet with an example of how you intend to use it?

Comment: Converter<Integer> c = Factory.getInstance(Integer.class); Dbobject converted = c.convert(New Integer(5));

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you see yourself going and editing the same function again and again to extend its functionality then thats a code smell. The problem is that whenever you add a type you have to add an if condition to your converter. So the conversion could be the class responsibility. in Java 8 you can use `Suppliers` for that and if you don't have Java 8 then `Guava` is your friend

```
 Supplier<DBObject> convertToDBObject(){ // java 8 code
   Supplier<DBObject> supplier = ()-> {
     BasicDBObject dbObject = new BasicDBObject();
     dbObject.append("age", this.getAge());
     dbObject.append("id", this.getId());
     return dbObject;
   } 
  return supplier;
 }
```

Or implement Guava suppliers anonymously if you running java 6 or 7.
You can add an interface for convertable things that your classes can implement.

```
interface DBObjectConvertable{
   Supplier<DBObject> convertToDBObject();
}
```

and by doing so your types will be responsible for converting to `DBObject` in their own ways. The code smell in your code is adding `ifs` to the factory.`Suppliers` are factories but in a `declarative` way, so instead of returning converted object immediately, I will return you a function that knows how to convert to `MongoDB` objects.

Comment: If I use interface DBObjectConvertable then why not to code "toDBObject()" method in every class I have without any "suppliers".. this is a shorter solution, I just thought its better to have a separate layer for these conversions.

Comment: @Dymytry because suppliers are lazy

Comment: myClassInstance.toDBObject() is not called until its really needed.